Analysing DCE with mixed logit in R
I am doing a Discrete Choice Experiment (DCE) with surveys for my research. My research is based on skincare products with different attribute levels/types. With a total of four attributes (each with 3 levels/types), I have generated 81 different products. I have separated them into 3 different surveys (each with 9 choice sets, each choice set has 3 products to choose from and respondents can only choose one of the three). Moreover, they also answered questions about their demographic and familiarity with certain brands (brands I used in the product design). These are the covariates (age group, income group, region of residence, familiarity of use for 6 different brands).
I have expanded the data in a long format (2430 rows in total because each respondent has considered over 27 products with differing attribute levels, and there are 90 respondents in total). I used this code to put into the mlogit model :
expanded_data <- expanded_data %>%
  mutate(
    Age = as.factor(Age),
    Income = as.factor(Income),
    Region = as.factor(Region),
    CeraVe = as.factor(CeraVe),
    Maybelline = as.factor(Maybelline),
    LOreal = as.factor(LOreal),
    LaMer = as.factor(LaMer),
    Chanel = as.factor(Chanel),
    Dior = as.factor(Dior),
    Price = as.factor(Price),
    Packaging = as.factor(Packaging),
    Quality = as.factor(Quality),
    Brand = as.factor(Brand),
    ProductChoiceBinary = as.logical(ProductChoiceBinary)
  )

mlogit_data <- mlogit.data(expanded_data, 
                           choice = "ProductChoiceBinary", 
                           shape = "long", 
                           id.var = "UniqueChoiceID", 
                           alt.var = "ProductID")

complex_model <- mlogit(ProductChoiceBinary ~ Price + Packaging + Quality + Brand | Age + Income + Region + CeraVe + Maybelline + LOreal + LaMer + Chanel + Dior, 
                        data = mlogit_data, 
                        random = ~ Price + Packaging + Quality + Brand | UniqueChoiceID)

But this error keeps on popping up: "Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) :
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0"
I have checked there is no multicollinearity and it might be the problem with how the data is structured. However, I am running out of time and I really need the result. Does anyone know what is wrong and what can I do?
I am not sure how to upload an image of my structure here. My data is structured with 2430 rows and 19 columns (RespondentID, Question, Product, Age, Region, Income, CeraVe, Maybelline, LOreal, LaMer, Chanel, Dior, ProductChoice, Price, Packaging, Quality, Brand, ProductChoiceBinary, UniqueChoiceID).
